# Critical: Is electronics.stackexchange.com getting answer that should be redirected to where?

Tags: discussion

I'm a member of http://electronics.stackexchange.com, it's a great community. But, I see some questions that are related to mechanical things, like that: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97579/how-to-attach-wheel-encoder-to-motor

Maybe it's that type of questions that is not fulfilling our beta *average questions*.

Someone has ideas on how we can contour this?

Answer (score 3):

Once upon a time [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange was "[Electronics and Robotics](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28/3774)" and there are still vestiges of that heritage on the site.

I would suggest that if you see questions which are marginally on topic for EE, but might be better off here, it might be worth adding a comment, linking to *Robotics*.

If something is off-topic on EE but on-topic here, I would flag it for migration, the mods there would probably be happy to have these things brought to their attention.